# Unit Test with transaction: CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, transactions

I have base class for my unit tests:

```
public abstract class DatabaseTestsBase
{
    protected OvuContext DbContext;
    protected TransactionScope TransactionScope;

    [SetUp]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        TransactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew);

        DbContext = new OvuContext("IntegrationTestContext");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        TransactionScope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And the test itself:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyEntityTests : DatabaseTestsBase
{
    [Test]
    public void MyEntity_Create_HasSucceeded()
    {
        var myEntity = new MyEntity(Guid.NewGuid());
        myEntity.Description = "bla bla bla";
        var id = myEntity.Id;

        DbContext.MyEntities.Add(myEntity);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();

        var temp = DbContext.MyEntities.Single(x => x.Id == id);

        ComparisonResult result = CompareLogic.Compare(myEntity, temp);

        Assert.True(result.AreEqual);
    }
}
```

I got the following error when the test runs:
CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction

The 'strange' thing is that when I run the test a second time, it passes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are taking the pattern of rolling back database side-effecting Integration / Unit Tests done under an uncommitted transaction (such as TransactionScope) a bit far :)

Code First EF is attempting to create the database under the context of the ambient `TransactionScope`, which isn't possible.

In Sql Server (and possibly other RDBMS's), [it isn't possible to execute certain statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191544(v=sql.105).aspx), such as `CREATE DATABASE`, command under a transaction. You'll get the same error if you execute the following directly in SSMS:

```
use master;

BEGIN TRAN
CREATE DATABASE FOO;
-- CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.
```

I would suggest that you change your strategy such that you pre-create a permanent, empty test database for testing. Other DDL statements executed by EF Code First, such as `CREATE TABLE` can be rolled back by the uncommitted `TransactionScope`.

Comment: I don't create a new database, it is an existing one that I use

Comment: Well, for whatever reason, the first time the UT is run, EF detects that the DB is missing. Check your connection strings?

Comment: the app.config of the unit test project has the correct connectionstring